# ElasticSearch Scroll API with multi threading

Tags: multithreading, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

First of all, I want to let you guys know that I know the basic work logic of how ElasticSearch Scroll API works. To use **Scroll** API, first, we need to call **search** method with some scroll value like **1m**, then it will return a **_scroll_id** that will be used for the next consecutive calls on Scroll until all of the doc returns within loop. But the problem is I just want to use the same process on multi-thread basis, not on serially. For example:

If I have 300000 documents, then I want to process/get the docs this way

- The 1st thread will process **initial** 100000 documents
- The 2nd thread will process **next** 100000 documents
- The 3rd thread will process **remaining** 100000 documents

So my question is as I didn't find any way to set the **from** value on scroll API how can I make the scrolling process faster with threading. Not to process the documents in a serialized manner.

**My sample python code**

```
if index_name is not None and doc_type is not None and body is not None:
   es = init_es()
   page = es.search(index_name,doc_type, scroll = '30s',size = 10, body = body)
   sid = page['_scroll_id']
   scroll_size = page['hits']['total']

   # Start scrolling
   while (scroll_size > 0):

       print("Scrolling...")
       page = es.scroll(scroll_id=sid, scroll='30s')
       # Update the scroll ID
       sid = page['_scroll_id']

       print("scroll id: " + sid)

       # Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll
       scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])
       print("scroll size: " + str(scroll_size))

       print("scrolled data :" )
       print(page['aggregations'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scroll must be synchronous, this is the logic.

You can use multi thread, this is exactly why elasticsearch is good for: parallelism.

An elasticsearch index, is composed of shards, this is the physical storage of your data. Shards can be on the same node or not (better).

Another side, the search API offers a very nice option: `_preference`(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html)

So back to your app:

1. Get the list of index shards (and nodes)
2. Create a thread by shard
3. Do the scroll search on each thread

Et voilà!

Also, you could use the elasticsearch4hadoop plugin, which do exactly that for Spark / PIG / map-reduce / Hive.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried a [sliced scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll)?  According to the linked docs:

> For scroll queries that return a lot of documents it is possible to
>   split the scroll in multiple slices which can be consumed
>   independently.

and

> Each scroll is independent and can be processed in parallel like any
>   scroll request.

I have not used this myself (the largest result set I need to process is ~50k documents) but this seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You should used sliced scroll for that, see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/817#issuecomment-372271460 on how to do it in python.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem as yours, but the doc size is 1.4 million. I've had to use concurrency method and use 10 threads for data writting.

I wrote the code with Java thread pool, and you can find the similar way in Python.

```
    public class ControllerRunnable implements  Runnable {
        private String i_res;
        private String i_scroll_id;
        private int i_index;
        private JSONArray i_hits;
        private JSONObject i_result;

        ControllerRunnable(int index_copy, String _scroll_id_copy) {
            i_index = index_copy;
            i_scroll_id = _scroll_id_copy;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                s_logger.debug("index:{}", i_index );
                String nexturl = m_scrollUrl.replace("--", i_scroll_id);
                s_logger.debug("nexturl:{}", nexturl);
                i_res = get(nexturl);

                s_logger.debug("i_res:{}", i_res);

                i_result = JSONObject.parseObject(i_res);
                if (i_result == null) {
                    s_logger.info("controller thread parsed result object NULL, res:{}", i_res);
                    s_counter++;
                    return;
                }
                i_scroll_id = (String) i_result.get("_scroll_id");
                i_hits = i_result.getJSONObject("hits").getJSONArray("hits");
                s_logger.debug("hits content:{}\n", i_hits.toString());

                s_logger.info("hits_size:{}", i_hits.size());

                if (i_hits.size() > 0) {
                    int per_thread_data_num = i_hits.size() / s_threadnumber;
                    for (int i = 0; i < s_threadnumber; i++) {
                        Runnable worker = new DataRunnable(i * per_thread_data_num,
                                (i + 1) * per_thread_data_num);
                        m_executor.execute(worker);
                    }
                    // Wait until all threads are finish
                    m_executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } else {
                    s_counter++;
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                s_logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you share the full code, starting with the SearchRequest